# How can I multiply vectors without a loop?

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(4,5,2)
```

and I want to multiply each element of `x` with each element in `y` and then sum it all up. So what I want to do is something along the lines of:

```
1*(4 + 5 + 2) + 2*(4 + 5 + 2) + 3*(4 + 5 + 2) = 11 + 22 + 33 = 66
```

Is there a way to do it without loops? Thanks in advance

Comment: many ways! what have you tried so far? have you found `?sum`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I'd use!

```
sum(x) * sum(y)
# [1] 66
```

Comment: That's cheating!!!!!!! :) +1 for the simplistic approach.  Logic beats programming skills.

Comment: So have I been flagged for migration to math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sum(x*sum(y))
[1] 66
```

Vectorised operators are neat!

`?mapply` is also a handy function to keep in mind when doing these sorts of tasks:
E.g.:

```
mapply("*",x,y)
```

...will do x[1] * y[1], x[2] * y[2] etc... to produce

```
mapply("*",x,y)
[1]  4 10  6
```

Summary functions like `sum` can also be used on one side, like:

```
mapply("*",x,sum(y))
[1] 11 22 33
```

Which means a long-hand way of doing your calculations would also be:

```
sum(mapply("*",x,sum(y)))
[1] 66
```

Answer (score 5):

Three other ideas besides Josh and thelatemail's excellent ideas:

```
sum(do.call("*", expand.grid(x, y)))
sum(outer(x, y)) ## or equivalently: sum(x %o% y)
sum(sapply(split(x, x), function(z) z * y))
```

Comment: and as a more explicit variant of the second `sum(outer(x, y, "*"))`

Answer (score 4):

We can use `x %*% t(y)` to get a matrix that has the products we want and then just use `sum` to add everything in the matrix together.

```
sum(x %*% t(y))
#[1] 66
```

---

And a slightly more efficient version of this same idea (Thanks to Gavin)

```
sum(tcrossprod(x, y))
#[1] 66
```

Comment: +1 `tcrossprod(x, y)` is supposed to be a slightly more efficient version of `x %*% t(y)`.